# How to find - write xpath for Text Between 2 Label Tag

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am need to find the xpath to get value 300 from the below html page. I have used xpath as //label[contains (text(),'of')]/following-sibling::text() - from stackoverflow answers - but it didn't work out well.  my next action is based on this value. So I need to read it.

```
<td class="clsLineCounterLabel">
<input id="lineCounter" class="clsLineCounter" tabindex="-1" size="4" value="0" readonly=""/>
<label id="lblOf" for="Of">of</label>
        300 
<label id="lblAllowedTextLines" for="AllowedTextLines">allowed text lines</label>
</td>
```

Any help ?

Comment: where is 300 present in this HTML code?

Comment: I just updated the question so that you can see HTML piece. Thanks for looking in to it.

Answer (score 0):

The text `300` belongs to the `<td>` tag. Try

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.className("clsLineCounterLabel")).getText();
```

`value` will be `300`.

And the xpath is

```
//td[@class='clsLineCounterLabel']
```

Comment: @Jaf-ManualQA Is it inside `iframe`?

Comment: NO. Its not iFrame. Its on normal HTML page only. The Input tag actually a field which will be increment once user start entering rows in to message area below. I.e. if user enter 3 rows, it will shown as 3 of 300 allowed lines.

Comment: @Jaf-ManualQA try //td[@class='clsLineCounterLabel']

Comment: It prints value as: null

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lineCounter]/parent::td")).getText();
```

Print value on console it will print you whole text of td, then filter integer value.

Hope this will work.

Thanks
Sadik

Comment: Sadik Ali, Unfortunately it did not work out. Element is not found at all to print complete text.   Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@id='lineCounter]/parent::td

Answer (score 0):

Getting the 300 is kind of tricky since it doesn't have its own node.

You could get the 300 with some JavaScript with the element as argument:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("lblOf"));
String txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", element);
```

Or with a single JavaScript call:

```
String txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "return document.getElementById('lblOf').firstChild.textContent;", element);
```

Or by extracting the number with a regex:

```
String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lblOf']/.."))
                   .getText().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```